# My Angular 6 project failing to build. node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts(12620,86): error TS1110: Type expected

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

Whenever i try to build the project i get the screenshot error message below. Have included my package.json file with the dependencies i use.

Been a few days struggling with the same problem and the solutions i have found are not working.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.4.1",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^9.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "^6.4.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "@syncfusion/ej2": "^17.4.51",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-schedule": "^17.4.51",
    "angular": "^1.8.2",
    "angular-material": "^1.1.9",
    "angular-password-strength-meter": "^2.0.0",
    "angular-webstorage-service": "^1.0.2",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
    "clie": "^0.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.6.12",
    "countup.js-angular2": "^6.0.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "ng-animate": "^0.3.3",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
    "ngx-loading": "^3.0.1",
    "rc-calendar": "^9.7.10",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.21.0",
    "rxjs": "6.3.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26",
    "zxcvbn": "^4.4.2"
  },
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.6.8",
    "@angular/cli": "^6.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "^2.8.0"
  }
```

[Image of the error message i get when i run the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGWf2.png)

Comment: Try update first You angular/cli and next install all dependecy again. I have project with similar dependecy but version is in hight level, and work good

Comment: what typescript version are you using? Have edited the question to include my typescript version

Comment: try to uninstall typescript and reinstall it. you can refer to get an idea: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/8769

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uninstall the version of TS that you're running on.
Install the latest version of TS available to you at that point

```
npm uninstall -D typescript 
npm i -D typescript@4.2.4
```

To get an idea you can refer this also: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/8769

Comment: thank you so much. 
I removed Typescript and installed 2.8.3 then updated
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the current version of Typescript with:
npm uninstall typescript --save
Then reinstall i with:
npm install typescript --save-dev